# Javafx Tables inside row table

Tags: javafx

I need to make a project using javafx where there is a table (for example of users), with another table inside each row (for example orders of the user).
I would like it to be toggle-able so I would extend a row by clicking on it and then the inner table/s would be visable.
Some draw for the gui exmaple:
[image: pic for example]

Comment: So far I tried some exmaple but it was only one table inside table with treetableview

Comment: Maybe a tree table would fit this better?

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve this kind of layout with a `TableView` or `TreeTableView` simply because the contains nodes that obviously span multiple columns which is supported by none of those controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be useful i guess

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableView extends Application {
private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    constructTable();
    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private void constructTable() {
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(getData());
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Person>() {
            Node detailsPane ;
            {
                this.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected ) {
                        detailsPane = constructSubTable(getItem());
                        this.getChildren().add(detailsPane);
                    } else {
                        this.getChildren().remove(detailsPane);
                    }
                    this.requestLayout();
                });

            }

            @Override
            protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
                if (isSelected()) {
                    return super.computePrefHeight(width)+detailsPane.prefHeight(60);
                } else {
                    return super.computePrefHeight(width);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                if (isSelected()) {
                    double width = getWidth();
                    double paneHeight = detailsPane.prefHeight(width);
                    detailsPane.resizeRelocate(0, getHeight()-paneHeight, width, paneHeight);
                } 
            }
        });
}

private TableView<Address> constructSubTable(Person person) {

    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>(); addresses.add(person.getAddress());

    TableView<Address> subTable = new TableView<Address>();
    TableColumn<Address, String> streetCol = new TableColumn<Address, String>("Street");
    streetCol.setMinWidth(100);
    streetCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Address, String>("Street"));

    TableColumn<Address, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<Address, String>("City");
    cityCol.setMinWidth(100);
    cityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Address, String>("city"));

    subTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(addresses));
    subTable.getColumns().addAll(streetCol, cityCol);
    subTable.setPrefHeight(50+(addresses.size()*30));
    subTable.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #42bff4;");
    return subTable;
}


private ObservableList<Person> getData() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com","Jacob Street","NY"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com","Isabella Street","DL"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com","Ethan Street"," ML"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com","Emma Street","EL"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com","Michael Street","ML"));
}

public static class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;
    private Address address;

    Person(String fName, String lName, String email,String streetS, String cityS) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        address = new Address(streetS, cityS);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}


 public static class Address{
    private final SimpleStringProperty street;
    private final SimpleStringProperty city;

    Address(String streetS, String cityS) {
        this.street = new SimpleStringProperty(streetS);
        this.city = new SimpleStringProperty(cityS);
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street.get();
    }

    public void setStreet(String streetS) {
        street.set(streetS);
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city.get();
    }

    public void setCity(String cityS) {
        city.set(cityS);
    }


 }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/sh9va/c81b9de44811cc860951701124941c1e

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TreeTableView in Scene Build and so adding the columns you want, aside from that, you should create the TabPane layout which will contain the information you want.

p.s do not forget to make a Model, TreeTableView needs a model to create the cells.

Comment: See this: [http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0670__JavaFX_Tree_Table_View.htm]